# Google Mail dropping some incoming messages

Tags: gmail

On a number of occasions over the last few weeks, emails sent by other people to my Google Mail account have not arrived. They are not in the Inbox, Trashcan or anywhere else. The sender does NOT receive any bounced notification. Other non-Google Mail recipients included in the emails DO receive them. What could be causing this? The sending mail SMTP server? Google Mail's servers? It's very frustrating not knowing when/if other incoming messages are just being dropped. Suggestions?

**Update:** This issue resolved itself. All the "lost" messages appeared in my Google Mail box weeks/months later. Some arrived on one day and some the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing that mailbox from more than one location? Potentially one could use POP3 and copies everything down without leaving a copy on the server and the second uses IMAP which is synched.

have you searched for: "from:recipient@email.com" without the quotes? and see if you find it?

Comment: I access my Google Mail from multiple locations. The messages which are not arriving are being sent directly to my Google Mail address. I do not have POP or IMAP enabled for Google Mail. I've searched for the email(s) in question but they are nowhere in Google Mail. I have confirmed that the sender is using the correct address. Other email recipients do receive the message.

Comment: @SabreWolfy Have you searched also in spam. They are excluded from normal search. Add `in:spam` to your search and try again.

Comment: @Andris: I checked Spam folder but they were not there. This has been resolved (I should have updated here earlier). I've updated my question.